# Creating a Tor 'hidden service' on Windows IoT Core

Tags: security, raspberry-pi, microsoft-windows-iot, azure

**The Background**

I'm prototyping some basic home automation software using Windows IoT Core and Azure.

I have built a Windows Universal Application that sends data to a Web App hosted in Azure via Web API. (token based auth)

**The Problem**

I don't want people sniffing my network and trying to breach either the Pi or the WebApp/database!

*- The data sent via API is very sensitive and should be untraceable.*

**Is it possible? If so, how?**

I've done some research into ways to secure a Pi by creating a 'Tor Hidden Service'.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKBKtDbhDko) explains how to set up a *Hidden Service* when running a LINUX based OS.

**THE QUESTION**

How would you go about creating a Tor Hidden Service in Windows IoT Core, and route the Universal Application traffic through Tor to Azure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tor seems overkill for what you're trying to do. If you want to prevent sniffing of data on the network, simply communicate with the server using SSL by installing a certificate on the server. You may also want to pay more attention to firewall rules to block incoming traffic using

> netsh advfirewall firewall

The pi is not very secure if anyone can get physical access as the SD card can be removed/replaced, so Tor won't help you much there. With physical access, it is possible for someone to get access to the token that you use for the service - it may be difficult but they could find it on the SD card.

Comment: I have already implemented SSL, there are specific benefits of a Tor Hidden Service I am after. If you watch the video i attached explaining its capabilities, you may understand. My VS solution is obfuscated, so no worries about the source code, and my token is not static. Every device has a uniquely generated ID, generated daily using various hardware info and hashed using SHA256 and then hashed again.  @simon

Comment: It seems, from the video, that you're wanting the Pi to act as a server. If you're posting data to a web service from the Pi, there should be no reason to run services on the Pi that are accessible - you should be able to do what you need without any ports open to the outside world, regardless of if they're hidden or not. Look at pub/sub, using MQTT or even Azure IoT hub (since you're in the MS space). Unless you're streaming video, as in the video, which it seems, from the question, that you're not doing.